# Is it normal practice to tip an Uber driver in London?

Tags: london, tipping, uber

I've never used Uber in London and will need to transfer from LHR to SW1. Is it customary to tip the Uber driver?

Comment: Since the question was in the close queue as "primarily opinion-based", I edited it from "Should I tip the driver?" to "Is it customary to tip the driver?" I think that's a reasonable, non-opinion question.

Comment: In the UK, it's not really expected of you that you tip *anyone*. People sometimes tip for exemplary service/food in restaurants, but you're not likely to be hassled if you don't.

Comment: @Prinsig I think it's quite normal to leave a tip in a restaurant for good (not necessarily exemplary) service.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that even in the tip-happy US, tipping of drivers in the Uber-branded ridesharing service is (officially) [not expected or required](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/22/travel/uber-taxi-tipping.html?_r=0), but is allowed. - Other "ridesharing" services (like Lyft) have different policies/expectations regarding tipping.

Comment: Just FYI, getting a Uber pickup at LHR is not straightforward. They are not permitted to wait at the airport. See http://uberdriverlondon.co.uk/uber-airport-pickups-london-drivers-side/ - they are required to wait offsite. There are plenty of transport options at LHR.

Comment: @Prinsig It is definitely expected to tip at restaurants with table service in the UK.

Comment: It's not expected anywhere, regardless of what you've heard. The entire point of Uber is to make payments painless and easy, using just your mobile phone. If tipping were common or expected, I would expect Uber to include it as a feature in their app. Until then, I refuse to tip Uber drivers. Uber clearly doesn't want me to, so drivers should understand not to expect tips. If drivers don't like this, they should take it up with Uber.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Uber drivers can meet you at the airport, you just have to wait for them to turn up. For Terminal 5, which I use quite regularly, it usually doesn't take more than ten minutes. I am not sure what is not straightforward—the app even tells you exactly where to meet the driver, there is a designated meeting spot for each terminal.

Comment: Even in the US you don't tip Uber drivers.

Comment: @MarkPattison What restaurants are you going to?? It's certainly *appreciated* if you tip in restaurants around here, but there's no expectation that I've ever known.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Any where your order is taken at the table, see e.g. [here](http://www.visitlondon.com/traveller-information/essential-information/money/tipping) or [here](http://gouk.about.com/od/ukcurrencymoneymatters/f/Tipping_UK.htm).  If they include a service charge on the bill, obviously there is no expectation to add more.

Comment: @MarkPattison I'm hesitant to rely on websites when I've lived here all my life and have quite literally never observed the expectation you're describing. Like I said, it's appreciated, but not an expectation.

Comment: Well, so have I.  Perhaps we live in different areas (I've lived mainly in the south) or have a different understanding of "expectation"?  I would always tip at least 10% unless the service has been terrible, and have almost always seen the same amongst fellow diners.

Comment: Probably a mix of both of those, @Mark - I've lived in various places, some northern, some southern.

Answer (score 27):

I will interpret your question as "is it normal practice to tip an Uber driver in London?"---otherwise it would be off topic as opinion-based.

**No**, it is not expected to tip Uber drivers.

It is also not expected to tip other kinds of taxi drivers in London, except that you might round up to the nearest convenient change if paying in cash.

Your Uber driver will be quite happy to be doing an LHR to SW1 transfer as it is.

Answer (score 15):

As others have said, there is no need.

But I'd like to point you to something else. **Don't use an Uber from LHR.** It is just going to cause you hassle.

Use the tube to get to SW1, Picadilly line till South Kensington and then District line for 2 stops to take you to the middle of SW1.

If your thought of taking an uber was because you'll have a lot of luggage, us ea service like airportr to bring it to your address, it'll be cheaper than the taxi and less faff, especially with a lot of luggage.

If time is at a premium, the fastest way would be Heathrow express to Paddington and then a taxi / uber or tube.

First trains leave around 5 am so even the first arrivals are no problem.

Seriously, don't drive from Heathrow into central London.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question. There are many reason to use uber or a taxi over the tube; particularly if you have luggage; you're travelling at rush hour and don't want to inconvenience commuters like me; you need to take a telephone call or need internet access for work on your journey; you're claustrophobic, et c. There are many reason not to use airportr, such as the fact you have to trust yet another third party not to lose or mishandle your luggage, it needs to be organized in advance, et c. There's really no "faff" in using uber.

Comment: He's right though.

Comment: @Calchas I do answer the question in my first sentence ;) And especially if travelling at rush hour a car will be a very bad idea. Claustrophobia, is a reason I guess, but I just wanted to point out that unlike in many other cities, and airports, LHR to central London is hands down best done by public transport. And the question suggests this would be his first trip to London, so he might not have been aware of this.

Comment: Counterpoint - I live "near" (20-30 min drive towards London) LHR and Uber is much more convenient/faster and if there's two of us travelling, about the same price as public transport.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is NO. There is no tip with Uber in London UK.

Answer (score 7):

From the drivers perspective, Uber's policy on tipping is the following:

- If someone wants to tip the driver, the driver has to say "It is not necessary to tip the driver when using Uber"
- If the person insists on the tip, the driver can accept it

Any driver I met would first say no to a tip, but then they would accept if I insist. I only do that if the service is really good.

Answer (score 3):

In general we tip when we get a good service; if a waitress served us well then we tip her. So why we don't do that for Uber drivers?

Well, simple answer: You can tip him, it will not cause any harm.

From a Uber [forum](http://uberpeople.net/threads/i-thought-we-didnt-tip-on-uber-how-do-we-do-that.3204/): You cannot tip from the app but you can give me him cash.

Also, there is this link about drivers who [added a sign for tips](http://therideshareguy.com/uber-tips-sign-review/).

Comment: Meh, you pay the driver for their work, why should they also get a tip for doing that work?  The "tipping" culture in the UK is *entirely* different to that in the US, as our service workers are not exempt from the minimum wage, so tipping here really does mean "you did an exceptional job, above what we should expect as the basics for our interaction", and not "heres some money because you get paid below minimum wage by your employer..."

Comment: okay maybe there is different culture but as I mentioned in my answer, the same you tip a waitress for good service you can tip the uber driver for his service ( if you like them ).

Comment: As I said, the Uber driver is already being paid for the service, something spectacular is going to have to happen for them to deliver something exceptional...  you don't tip a bus driver, a train driver et al.  IMHO tipping is getting out of hand, and people expect tips just for doing the basic job - that is what we need to prevent.

Comment: usually people tips a waitress right , but she get her salary after all, and shes not doing something exceptional. or in uk you dont tip waitress ? @Moo

Comment: In the UK you only tip if the service is exceptional - not simply for the service.  The waitress/waiter gets a full wage here and does not rely on tips, as they do in the US.

Comment: @Moo I don't even meet the train driver. I pay the bus driver before the journey and, in any case, s/he has very little latitude to give good or bad service (for example, they're not free to choose a better route to avoid traffic). Neither a bus driver nor a train driver is giving personal service to me. In the UK, I don't generally tip taxi drivers but I think that they're a different case to bus and train drivers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree - a service is being paid for in each case, its just in some that the customer has been conditioned to believe that the cost is not simply "advertised cost" but "advertised cost plus a decent amount on top...".

Comment: @Moo there are a few states where wait staff are required to be paid minimum wage, and you are still expected to tip 20% even if the service is mediocre. And all states are required to bring their staff up to minimum wage if they don't get the difference in tips. It's definitely a culture thing, not really related to wages.

Comment: in the UK, taxi drivers are often self-employed, so they may not actually get the minimum wage. There was a legal case about Uber last year, which found the drivers should receive the minimum wage, but don't know if that has actually happened.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Long distance coaches often take different routes to avoid traffic, eg Oxford to Heathrow they can divert via the M4 if the M40 is bad. The drivers will also help you stow your luggage under the coach. Don't think I've ever seen anyone try to tip them though, despite meeting your requirements!

Comment: @Gagravarr Fair point about long-distance coaches -- I'd only considered inner-city buses. However, to take your specific example of the Oxford-to-Heathrow coaches, the driver doesn't "help you store your luggage": they insist on doing it themself. Them storing and retrieving passengers' luggage is just a regular part of their job.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I quite often stash my own bags / get them off on the Oxford-Heathrow bus, drivers seem quite happy as long as you check which section with them. One could also say `just a regular part of their job` applies to uber drivers and driving you somewhere...

Comment: @Moudiz almost nowhere in europe tips just for tipping, for a matter of fact. In spain it's just in case of a very exceptional service, and so is in france and belgium, the places i've been most. And very means VERY. I don't get tipped to code cleanlier, but i do it because it's my job.

Comment: I have actually only tipped once, where a waitress took the excepcional job of satisfying my "well-made-meat" request against all odds ( including a random client bumping her and making the food fall 1m away from the table, and many joke material situations).

Comment: @CptEric well it seems depending on the culture , where I live its more like a [Prestige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige) than a satsfying service

Comment: so you pay more than the fixed price because it's fun? culturally doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Also, Showing off is seen as bad on most of the cultures i've mentioned. @Moudiz

Comment: @CptEric yes its something bad and i hate it,trust me when i be on a date/with girls or 'important/bussinesse' guys you should tips to show good impression. i had once problem with that