# Is it normal to tip an Uber driver in Canada?

Tags: tipping, uber

What's the answer if I:

1. have luggage, like checked baggage for flights?
2. don't have any luggage?

If I ought to tip, how much? Thanks!

This is the Canadian version of [Is it normal practice to tip an Uber driver in London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86756/92533) and [Is it normal/expected to tip taxi drivers in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25453/92533)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience as a Canadian citizen, it's normal (though not necessarily expected) to tip taxi drivers a few dollars per trip, and I don't see why it would be different for Uber drivers. I would say if you have heavy luggage or many smaller pieces that it's polite to tip a couple dollars or so extra for their trouble, though it's still up to you.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer, I don't uber, but used Teo before if closed down last month in Montréal).

I usually tip a couple of bucks for the ride and maybe a one or two bucks additional if driver is a good driver (takes care of luggage, drive safely, or is not overly talkative).

Comment: The question isn't asking for individual people to state what they do. Maybe you're unusually generous; maybe you're super-stingy. The question is about what behaviour is expected.